# free software to test my laptop components

Tags: stress-test

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What programs can I use to test my computer's hardware?](https://superuser.com/questions/351617/what-programs-can-i-use-to-testmy-computers-hardware)

i need some tools to check when/if my laptop can resists on hight computing requirements. Now i'm workin on a different machine, but, some time ago, when i was using that laptop it wqas crushing a lot(shutting down without warning).
I was using a win 7 x86 on a x64 machine. I wana see if that was the causes of the crushers

ty.

Answer (score 2):

[Speedfan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) can monitor temperature
[Orthos](http://www.overclock.net/downloads/138142-orthos.html)/[Prime95](http://www.mersenne.org/freesoft.htm) can stress the CPU (I recommend Prime95 - Orthos isn't well maintained any longer.)
[Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) can test your RAM
[Furmark](http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/) can test your graphics card
[SmartMonTools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smartmontools/) can yank S.M.A.R.T. data off of almost any hard drive