# Computer freezes after watching Youtube videos

Tags: firefox, freeze, video-streaming

I had Windows 7 installed all september. But I installed Windows XP Professional back because my computer couldn't handle the new OS.

After first boot I tried to install newest flash player (from `Adobe` website), but it failed. I had my old setup on USB drive and it worked. I don't know is it important or not.

I am watching Youtube videos in my free time (almost every hour). After few days the computer started to freeze when I **open a page with the video** or **close the page with video**, **not while I watch a video**. No BSODs. Nothing in Event viewer. I use Firefox only.

When computer freezes the sound wont. If iTunes is playing a radio station or is it another video playing in background, the sound wont freeze.

Last few days the mouse wont freeze. Its a strange symptom. If I click few times then the cursor will actually freeze.

I just want to know where does this problem come from (hardware - graphics card, old motherboard or it's just some glitch in setups). If it's not graphics card then I will be happy. The graphics card is ATI Radeon HD 4650 - brand new.

Catalyst 11.8 installed.

Things I **have tried**:

- Installed newest flash player after a week (the setup didn't fail this time)
- Installed latest video drivers
- Deleting cookies
- Defragmenting hard drive
- Using TuneUp utilities for computer cleenup
- Installed latest Mozilla Firefox
- Cleaned the PC
- Changed CPU Fan speed almost to max (just to be sure)

Things I **haven't tried yet**:

- Didn't try playing videos on other browsers

What can I do now?

Comment: Sound like your graphics card (video freezing but sound continuing).  You can perhaps try to perform some disk checks and memory tests to rule them out.

Comment: @techie007 could you tell what program can I use to test my video card, please?

Comment: Check out http://superuser.com/questions/8593/what-is-the-best-computer-burn-in-or-stability-testing-software for some testing software for various components.

Comment: Also check out http://superuser.com/questions/351617/what-programs-can-i-use-to-testmy-computers-hardware

Answer (score 3):

Try right clicking the video while it's playing, and Uncheck "Enable hardware acceleration".

[image]

Comment: Thanks never thougth of that, but now I need to open a bunch of videos to try it out.

Comment: I think the problem is gone. The only problem that sometimes video lags.

Comment: @Roberts The lag might just be your computer hardware

Comment: @Simon Sheehan I know, that's why I used the "old-hardware" tag. I have old but still functional PC, with new video card. So Im woring about video card.

Comment: @Roberts What are the specs?

Comment: @Simon Sheehan Click on my username.

Comment: Sorry but this answer only helped but didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Sounds like the problem clearly lies in your graphics card's hardware video acceleration.  I would try either updating the drivers again (if there is a newer release), OR DOWNGRADING your drivers back to a version from 6 months old.  I have seen several video cards where the newer drivers have bugs and yet the old releases are rock solid.

Comment: Maybe driver roll back will solve the freezing, but I don't want to use old drivers because I had them installed about month and video card was randomly crashing and it was hard to do something. You can check my other questions and you will find out a lot of problems with old graphics driver.

Answer (score 0):

Try a LiveUSB to see if it still occurs.  If so, likely hw.  Better yet, install Linux on the machine as well so you can dual boot.

Comment: I have completely different computer now =D